# Why does keycloak set wrong execution of another required action?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

Now we are about to use keycloak 14 (after 10.0.2).

And i found strange problem with 14 kc.

We have two custom required actions which have correct order on the page with required actions(in admin console). I add this actions to user. And after redirect to the first action i found that execution parameter in the uri was setted in wrong value(value for another required action). So links don't work correctly on the page because of it(got error page with loginTimeout message error).

Found place in kc code where execution parameter is setted

[AuthenticationManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkEzC.png)

On 1035 line in reqAction variable i have wrong required action name. I think this value have to be setted using required action priority. Is it bug? Or i do smth wrong?

On keycloak 10.0.2 i didn't find this problem.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Error appears for totp page  while forming manualUrl attribute

Answer (score 0):

this is probably already too late but I thought for any other people in the future its still nice to see one answer.
I  had the exact same problem and I was able to solve it for me. I don't know if it will also work for you.

Apparently, there was one part in my own custom code where I add actionB and **before** actionA.

```
user.addRequiredAction("actionB"); //added first 
user.addRequiredAction("actionA"); //added second
```

But in the rank (under Authentication > required Action in Keycloak) actionA is above actionB and therefore is shown first to the user.
However,  it seems like the actions are saved in the order given by the code (makes sense) and the url the user is redirected after login does not take the rank into account and therefore the url is:

*[website]/auth/realms/bpc/login-actions/required-action?execution=**actionB**[...]*

which of course causes problems with the generated links in the form.

Once I changed the order in the code to reflect the actual ranking, everything worked perfectly.